# MATLAB put a LED to a serial port

Tags: matlab, serial-port, led

I'm working on MATLAB, I want to connect only a LED & resistor to a serial port.

When a specific action happens in my program, the LED must turn on.

What I did but nothing had happened:

```
S   = serial( 'com1' );
fid = fopen( s );                         # ... 've checked the s vs. S ?
```

Comment: This cannot work, you need a device that is able to "talk" to the computer to establish the serial connnection. You can look for instance at arduino boards, but there are many other options.

Comment: This is not a programming question, since it's essentially a problem of lacking hardware.

Comment: Thanks, but i need a simple board which only consist of resistor and a led then I will connect them to the pc through the serial port. Any help please how to code it

Comment: Again, this is simply not possible. This is not how thing work.

Comment: What can I do in this situation, if u have any solution.

Comment: @Ratbert: no special hardware is needed. On can connect LEDs with resistors directly to a serial port with no additional hardware ([see here](http://slicksolutions.eu/ledsdriver.shtml) for example). This doesn't mean that it's a good or robust idea, however. And Matlab's `serial` class is unlikely to work for this. A lower level means of sending data to the serial port will be required.

Comment: @horchler OK, I didn't knew about that, thanks or the link.

Comment: It should be working... serial port do not require impedance checking or wake up acknowlegment messages prior sending bytes.... I suggest you try with a third party tool -Hyperterminal :)- and with a tester over pins 2&3 and see what happens.....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control the `DTR` and `RTS` lines (on DB-9 connectors on pins 4 and 7, respectively) from MATLAB. According to the reference, serial port objects have the properties `DataTerminalReady` and `RequestToSend`, which can be toggled. For example,

```
S = serial('com1');
for ii = 1:5
    set(S, 'RequestToSend', 'on');
    pause(1)
    set(S, 'RequestToSend', 'off');
    pause(1)
end
```

will flash an LED connected to the `RTS` pin five times.